# MySQLDataTruncation: Out of range value for column

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

I am inserting a row using ibatis and a java webapp. The POJO has a field which needs to store a number (like 3.0 or 2.34). I have tried using BigDecimal and Double on the java side. On the MySQL side, I am using a Decimal(5, 5) data type.

When I try to insert a row which has "4" as the value for this numeric field, MySQL and iBatis throw the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SqlMapClient operation: encountered SQLException [  
--- The error occurred in org/mySQL.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a result map.  
--- Check the mySQL.insertQuery.  
--- The error happened while setting a property on the result object.  
--- Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SqlMapClient operation: encountered SQLException [  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the insertQuery-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (update failed).  
--- Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'numericColumn' at row 316]; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:188)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithRowHandler(GeneralStatement.java:133)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryWithRowHandler(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:649)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryWithRowHandler(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:156)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryWithRowHandler(SqlMapClientImpl.java:133)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$5.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:267)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:165)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryWithRowHandler(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:265)
    at org.myClass(myClass.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:248)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:165)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:66)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:191)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:516)
```

Am I using the wrong java data type for the value to be inserted? If not, why won't MySQL let me insert the value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to have misunderstood how defining a `DECIMAL` (or potentially `NUMERIC`) column works in SQL -
Specifically, when defining the column as `DECIMAL(x, y)`, `x` is the *total* number of digits the column will store, and `y` is the number of digits *after* the decimal point.  So, in your column definition, you specified a range of **-1 < column < 1**.  The datatype is correct, but you're attempting to specify a value outside the range the column was told to allow.
Fortunately, the fix is simple: change the column definition.  I'm assuming you want to have up to 5 digits *before* the decimal point, which would make the column definition `DECIMAL(10, 5)`.